# Is there a 'Related List - Single' component for Communities?

Tags: lightning, community, aura, community-builder

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to display a single Related List on a page in my Community. This is available on Lightning internally, however I can't find anything remotely close for Communities.

I suspect this will need to be created using a custom component, can someone point me in the right direction on how this can be built if not available out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Single related list is not available for the community. You have to create a custom component to achieve this. Please follow the below trailhead to create a custom component but I would recommend you to fetch the object details using Design resource of a component so that you can use the same component for other objects but the only problem here is you have to define the set of columns (Hard code) or else you can get those details from designer of a lightning component but you have to define the number in designer.

Datalist custome Document (Sample):
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/slds-lightning-components-workshop/steps/slds-lc-4

Desgin Resource Document:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm

Answer (score 5):

Related List - Single is now available in Lightning Community Builder.
If you don't see it, try going to the Community Builder > Settings > Advanced > Show all components.[image: Community Builder Related List Single Screenshot] [image: Community Builder Show all components Screenshot]